# To combine html class in css for easy design?

Tags: html, css, web

I am a newbie in web development, I have an HTML document with some classes, however, while designing I came across these This is my HTML doc snippet:

```html
  <button class="roll"><i class="ion-ios-loop"></i><span>Roll dice</span></button>
 <button class="hold"><i class="ion-ios-download-outline"></i><span>Hold</span></button>
```

and i have written css like this:

```css
.hold span{
    padding-left: 10px;
    transition: .2s;
}
.roll span{
    padding-left: 10px;
    transition: .2s;
}
.roll span:hover{
     padding-left: 20px;
}
.hold span:hover{
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

However, i tried to make it shorter like this, it was not working properly:

```css
.hold.roll span{
    padding-left: 10px;
    transition: .2s;
}

.hold.roll span:hover{
     padding-left: 20px;
}
```

and also like this:

```css
.hold,.roll span{
    padding-left: 10px;
    transition: .2s;
}

.hold,.roll span:hover{
     padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Is there something which I am missing about CSS ? Thanks, why my other 2 code is not working. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give like this

```
.hold span,.roll span{
 padding-left: 10px;
 transition: .2s;
}

.hold span:hover,.roll span:hover{
 padding-left: 20px;
}
```

or you can also write as

```
button span{
 padding-left: 10px;
 transition: .2s;
}

button span:hover{
 padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: just let me try :-)

Comment: @AlpitAnand  hmm most welcome....:) If this answer is helpful for you then pls accept it as correct answer.

Comment: for sure, i will in 3min, stackover policy :p

Answer (score 1):

**You need to add separate rule for each span,**
example:

```
.hold span,.roll span{
    padding-left: 10px;
    transition: .2s;
}

.hold span:hover,.roll span:hover{
     padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this, the issue was you `.hold.roll span` or `.hold,.roll span` is not acceptable, is should be `.hold span,.roll span`

```css
.hold span , .roll span{
    padding-left: 10px;
    transition: .2s;
}
.roll span:hover , .hold span:hover{
     padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button class="roll"><i class="ion-ios-loop"></i><span>Roll dice</span></button>
 <button class="hold"><i class="ion-ios-download-outline"></i><span>Hold</span></button>
```

Comment: Thanks, dont forget to check it as helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You can also add more than one class for a object, lets say you have two classes in your css file:

```
.default-padding {padding:6px}
.button {background:#c00;}

<input type="button" class="default-padding button"></button>
<label class="default-padding">Label</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine as many selectors as you wnat, but all of them must be completely defined. Here's a nice article about this issue: [Grouping Multiple CSS Selectors](https://www.thoughtco.com/grouping-multiple-css-selectors-3467065).

This is what you are looking for:

```
.hold span, .roll span{
    padding-left: 10px;
    transition: .2s;
}
.roll span:hover, .hold span:hover{
     padding-left: 20px;
}
```